# I have tried to generate river network but it is not according to reality. Instead it shows very small lines?

Tags: rivers

I want to show river network on DEM data of a region. The procedures that I have followed:

1. Downloaded the DEM data of area and add it to QGIS
2. Clipped the study area out of it through Raster tool
3. Changed its projection to projected one
4. Used fill sinks (Wang & Liu) tool under Terrain analysis
5. Then used Channel Network and Drainage basins

But my DEM data shows small lines instead of river networks and it does not match the reality. Need help in resolving the issue.[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Can you clarify how you "Changed its projection to projected one" ? that's the step beginners often get wrong.

Comment: What is the source of your DEM?

Comment: To change the projection to projected one, I use Raster-> Projections-> Wrap (Reproject) and regarding source of DEM, 

I have tried with DEM from two sources 1. https://opentopography.org/ and 2. QGIS-> Plugins-> SRTM downloader. 
Both generate same results

Comment: Gentle reminder if it missed generous expert's view. Hoping little help in this respect